# IOS can't run Javascript code

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm using uiwebview, my work is searching for href links which have values equal to 'https://mylink.com/'  and click on the first link found in webview programmatically by uibutton, I tried this but it hasn't work

```
    NSString *jsStat = @"var alink= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(i=0;i<alink.length;i++) {
        if(alink[i].href=='https://mylink.com/'){
            alink[i].click(); return;
        }
    }";
    [self.ob_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsStat];
```

If I try `jsStat=@"alert('a')`, it's fine, and I run the js code in the chrome console without any problem.

Comment: Next time, please indent your code!

Comment: This way, If I copy it into XCode it will generate errors:) new lines should be escaped.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this so I don't have experience :) sorry

Comment: @user3304357 - the alink (SPACE) .length is mistake when you typed question?

Comment: have you tried "var alink = document.getElementsByTagName('a');alert(alink);" ?

Comment: yes :( mistake again @@!

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked when i remove "return" in the js code :)